# Chimpchat automatic journey

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

My goal is to make a monkey visit all pages/activity of a given android application.
I am currently using Chimpchat and my first steps are as following :

**1 - Connection to the device :**

```
TreeMap<String, String> options = new TreeMap<String, String>();
options.put("backend", "adb");
options.put("adbLocation", ADB);
mChimpchat = ChimpChat.getInstance(options);
mDevice = mChimpchat.waitForConnection(TIMEOUT, ".*");
mDevice.wake();
```

**2 - Getting a list of view IDs :**

```
mDevice.getViewIdList();
```

**3 - For each strings (using iterator it) ID contains in list returned by getViewIdList(), I would like to access Class, Text if any, bounds, etc ...**

```
 while (it.hasNext()) {
        String s = it.next();
        System.out.println(s + " : ");
        try {
            IChimpView v = mDevice.getView(By.id(s));
            System.out.println(v);
            System.out.println(v.getViewClass() + "  : " );
            if (v.getViewClass().toString() == "TextView") {
                System.out.print(v.getText());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I get an exception on the

```
v.getViewClass()


com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpException: Node with given ID does not exist
at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager.queryView(ChimpManager.java:415)
at com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpView.queryView(ChimpView.java:53)
at com.android.chimpchat.core.ChimpView.getViewClass(ChimpView.java:96)
at JavaMonkey.listViewsID(JavaMonkey.java:80)
at JavaMonkey.main(JavaMonkey.java:114)
```

If anyone can point my mistake(s) or point me to another approach, it would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: It doesn't look like you've started an activity yet, so there would be no application yet to crawl.  However as to how to start the activity in ChimpChat, I'm still trying to figure that out.  Here's the method thought that should do it.     `mDevice.startActivity@Nullable String uri, @Nullable String action, @Nullable String data, @Nullable String mimeType, Collection<String> categories, Map<String, Object> extras, @Nullable String component, int flags)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the issue is that there is no Activity running.
As I commented above you might be able to use `startActivity` to start one.
However that will take some digging to figure out what all needs to be passed in.
Another solution is as follows:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n ");
builder.append(mPackage).append("/").append(mActivity);
String output = mDevice.shell(builder.toString());
```

This will use the adb shell to launch the application.
`mPackage` = the package path (com.company.application) and `mActivity` = the activity (.MyActivity).  From there you should be able to `mDevice.getHierarchyViewer()` or `mDevice.getViewIdList()`

Answer (score 1):

I think [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) would be much better suited for this type of testing. Accessing views on a remote device using adb/MonkeyRunner is not very reliable in my experience. In addition, Robotium has a bunch of cool features and can be easily integrated into an existing test suite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Robotium is a great tool (as Selendroid) but the fact that it needs to resign the tested apk is a no-go for me. I have to make this work without the keystore and  without a rooted device.